# Postgres query performance monitoring on production servers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

My goal here is to identify slow queries, which can be done using slow query logs i.e increase the timeout in postgresql.conf to be some 100ms (acceptable query time) and then identify the slow queries.

This has a number of issues, one being the query was slow during that time, but it is faster when run again.The best way is to get an average and then work on the queries which are slow on average.

This requires `pg_stat_statements` extension which is supposed to cause 10% of server performance degradation, taken from [here](http://pgsnaga.blogspot.in/2011/10/performance-impact-of-pgstatstatements.html), the blog post is pretty old and things might have improved.

My questions

- I could not find any authoritative source on how performance impact would pg_stat_statemtents extension would have.Is this negligible in recent versions ?
- If it is indeed causing a performance impact, will it be sufficient to take a backup/export the system tables required for pg_stat_statements and then analyze it offline in a separate machine perhaps, is there any extension/module which does this automatically
- Any alternate solutions are also welcome

Comment: Why don't you just check for yourself how much `pg_stat_statements` slows down _your_ system? A quick test using `pg_bench` might already be enough. And I don't understand why you would need to backup the system tables just to analyze them. _If_ there is an overhead it's the logging of the statements most probably not the query on them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : You are right about the backup part,I was not paying attention.Regarding the checking of how much it slows down, we are not yet in production and since pg_stat it is somewhat widespread utility,I wanted to know if there is any known impact,but yes I would definitely want to run and see how slow it is for my setup.

Comment: This tool might be an alternative: https://www.vividcortex.com/resources/network-analyzer-for-postgres/

Comment: You can get Postgres to [log all queries](http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/06/logstatement-postgres-all-full-logging.html), and then feed the server logs into [pgBadger](https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger), which spits out some nice HTML reports. Having a record of every query can also be invaluable for debugging. But if the overhead of logging everything is too much, you can restrict it to long-running queries with the `log_min_duration_statement` setting.

Comment: Curious to know what you ended up going with? What would you suggest today